# grails filter (findAllByName)

Tags: grails

the gsp

```
<g:form controller="sort" action="filteren">
            <g:select from="${functionremote.Sort.list() }" 
            onchange="this.form.submit()" 
            value="${flash.filter}"
            name="filter"
            optionKey="id" 
            noSelection="['':'selecteer']"/>
        </g:form>
```

the controller

```
def filteren={
    def filterlist
    flash.filter=params.filter

    if(params.filter!=''){
        filterlist=Sort.findAllByName{params.filter)
    }else
        filterlist=Sort.list()

    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)

    render(view:'list', model:[sortInstanceList:filterlist, sortInstanceTotal:filterlist.count()])
}
```

what's wrong with the filter?

```
filterlist=Sort.findAllByName{params.filter)
```

when I do this:

```
 filterlist=Sort.findAllByName{"some string")
```

it works pefectly

thanks

Comment: If you do a println params do you see filter in it?

Comment: i kinda noticed that you used a curly brace for the opening (e.g. ...findAllByName {...) instead of ...findAllByName(...) )... try parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that it is not working, since `params.filter` will be an ID instead of a name, since your `optionKey` value is ID. Change the query to be like:

```
filterlist = Sort.findAllById(params.filter)
```

or in this case

```
filterlist = Sort.get(params.filter)
```